# How to implement Orientation-like property for a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I crated a custom template for a ToggleButton used for expanding/collapsing a piece of a control.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ShowHideToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <system:Double x:Key="DefaultPathThickness">3</system:Double>
        <system:Double x:Key="MouseOverPathThickness">4</system:Double>
        <Geometry x:Key="HidePathData">M 0,0 7,7 0,14</Geometry>
        <Geometry x:Key="ShowPathData">M 7,0 0,7 7,14</Geometry>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border Name="BoundingBorder" CornerRadius="15,0,0,15" Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundBrush}">
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path Name="path" Stroke="{StaticResource DefaultTextBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource DefaultPathThickness}" Data="{StaticResource HidePathData}"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value ="True">
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource HidePathData}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value ="False">
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource ShowPathData}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value ="True">
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverPathThickness}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value ="False">
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="{StaticResource DefaultPathThickness}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here you can see what it looks like:

[image: My ToggleButton]

I'd like to use it also on the top, bottom, and right sides of a control so I have to somehow rotate it. Actually I want to implement something like orientation with 4 states.

My first attempt was to do it outside of the template:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource ShowHideToggleButtonTemplate}" IsChecked="{Binding DropBox.IsShown}"
          Height="50" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
            <TranslateTransform Y="-12.5"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
</ToggleButton>
```

[image: My ToggleButton after rotation]

As you can see the bounding rectangle of the button is still vertical, which leaves empty space below the button.

Things to do:

1. Update the bounding rectangle to fit the actual button's rectangle
2. Support 4 states (left, right, top, bottom)
3. When I use one of the horizontal states (top or bottom) the Width should become Height and Height should become Width.
4. Translation Y should not by hardcoded (it depends on button's width and height)

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use the LayoutTransform instead of the RenderTransform, because the LayoutTransform can update layout bounding.